# Замена в Simulink стандартного блока функцией

Tags: matlab

Всем день добрый. Есть в Matlab пример модели - doc_fmmoddemod.slx. Хочу заменить блок модулятора на блок с m-файлом? Написал скрипт:

```
function y = fcn(u)

coder.extrinsic('fmmod');
fs = 100;
fc = 4;
freqdev = 50;
fmmod(u,fc,fs,freqdev);
y = u;
```

Но графики модулированного и демодулированного сигналов совсем другие получаются. Помогите разобраться. Может чего в скрипте дописать нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша функция в данном случае ничего не делает, т.к. вы выход приравняли ко входу

```
fmmod(u,fc,fs,freqdev);    
y = u;
```

попробуйте вот так

```
function y = fcn(u)

coder.extrinsic('fmmod');
fs = 100;
fc = 4;
freqdev = 50;
z = fmmod(u,fc,fs,freqdev);
y = zeros(size(u));
y = z;
```

Я так полагаю вы хотите заменить FM Modulator Baseband (из doc_fmmoddemod.slx), так почему бы его и не использовать (код для примера doc_fmmoddemod.slx):

```
function y = fcn(u)
fs = 1e3;              % Sample rate (Hz)
fd = 50;               % Frequency deviation (Hz)
H = comm.FMModulator('FrequencyDeviation', fd, 'SampleRate', fs);

y = step(H, u);
```

Comment: Написал вот таким образом:                                                         
     function y = fcn(u)

     coder.extrinsic('fmmod');
     fs = 100;
    fc = 4;
    freqdev = 50;
    fmmod(u,fc,fs,freqdev);

     y = fmmod(u,fc,fs,freqdev);                                                                                                         Дак теперь выдает ошибку "Function output 'y' cannot be an mxArray in this context. Consider preinitializing the output variable with a known type.". Я просто ни разу не сталкивался с такой работой. Что означает такая ошибка?

Comment: Попробовал в первом варианте, аналогично выдавал "Function output 'y' cannot be an mxArray in this context. Consider preinitializing the output variable with a known type." Это ошибка неправленого типа данных, который выдаёт fmmod, т.к. эта функция скорее всего вызывается из С/С++ библиотеки. Для корректной работы нужно заранее объявить выходной массив. Решение в ответе.